# Perl IPConfig class

Tags: perl

I've got a Perl script with the following in it:

```
use IPConfig;
my $ipconf = new IPConfig("eth1");
```

My problem is that I can't find ANY information about the IPConfig class.

I *can* find reference to [Win32::IPConfig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-IPConfig/lib/Win32/IPConfig.pm), but I can't imagine it being relevant as the class I'm interested in has a method called `listIP`, and this one doesn't

Is this likely to be some custom class?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can try to search for the `.pm` file on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it could be custom class, and you can check it's file location,

```
print grep /IPConfig/i, values %INC;
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a custom class that someone snuck into the system without telling anyone else about. Cheers